# Is this equivalent to (some version of) Hechler forcing?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, descriptive-set-theory

Let $\omega^{<\omega}$ be the set of finite strings of naturals, and let $\omega^{<\omega}_{\not=\emptyset}$ be the set of nonempty finite strings of naturals. Consider the following forcing notion:

- A condition is a pair $(p,\Sigma)$ where $p$ is a finite partial map $\omega^{<\omega}_{\not=\emptyset}\rightarrow \omega^{<\omega}_{\not=\emptyset}$, $\Sigma$ is a total map $\omega^{<\omega}_{\not=\emptyset}\rightarrow \omega^{<\omega}_{\not=\emptyset}$, and $p\subset\Sigma$.
- We set $(p,\Sigma)\le (q,\Pi)$ iff $p\supseteq q$ and for all $\sigma\in \omega^{<\omega}_{\not=\emptyset}$ there are some (possibly empty) strings $\eta,\theta\in\omega^{<\omega}$ such that $$\Sigma(\sigma)=\eta\Pi(\sigma\eta)\theta.$$

Basically, $\Sigma(\sigma)$ is determined by first adding some "noise" $\eta$, then applying $\Pi$ to the modified string $\sigma\eta$, then adding some more "noise" $\theta$ - but in each case we're allowed to add no "noise" at all. As an example of how this works, note that any two conditions with the same "stem" have a common refinement: if $(p,\Sigma_1),(p,\Sigma_2)$ are conditions, then so is $(p,\Pi)$ where $$\Pi: \sigma\mapsto \Sigma_1(\sigma)\Sigma_2(\sigma\Sigma_1(\sigma))$$ for all $\sigma\not\in dom(p)$ (for $\sigma\in dom(p)$ we set $\Pi(\sigma)=p(\sigma)$).

My question is how this forcing relates to Hechler forcing:

> Is $\mathbb{P}$ equivalent to Hechler forcing?

All that's obvious to me at the moment is that $\mathbb{P}$ adds a Hechler generic. It is not even clear to me that Hechler forcing adds a $\mathbb{P}$-generic (in fact, I suspect it doesn't).

While my primary interest is in "simple" Hechler forcing, I'd also be interested in the situation with respect to any of its common variations; see e.g. [Justin Palumbo's Ph.D. thesis](https://escholarship.org/content/qt41f4123s/qt41f4123s_noSplash_f1de35921e305ecdfd4d155fbc6c17f1.pdf).

EDIT: More generally, I'd be interested in anything that can be said about the broader class of "$\Pi^0_2$-Hechler forcings:" moving back to $\omega$ for simplicity, such a forcing has as its conditions pairs $(p,F)$ with $p\in\omega^{<\omega}$ and $F\in\omega^\omega$ extending $p$, and has ordering given by $$(p,F)\le (q,G)\quad\iff\quad p\supseteq q\mbox{ and }\varphi(F,G)$$ for some $\Pi^0_2$ sentence $\varphi$ in the language of arithmetic with symbols for $F$, $G$, and application. For instance, Hechler forcing itself corresponds to taking $\varphi$ = "$\forall x(F(x)\ge G(x))$" while the forcing $\mathbb{P}$ of this question is at first glance "properly $\Pi^0_2$."

---

Here's why I'm specifically comparing $\mathbb{P}$ to Hechler(ish) forcing. Intuitively, a sufficiently $\mathbb{P}$-generic filter yields a sufficiently good stationary Banach-Mazur strategy for player $2$ *(and both stationarity and player-$2$-winning are appropriately WLOG here)*. This lets us prove the (2)-to-(1) direction of the following result:

> For a real $\alpha$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\alpha$ is hyperarithmetic.
> 2. There is some set $A\subseteq\omega^\omega$ whose Banach-Mazur game $G_{BM}(A)$ is determined such that any winning strategy for $G_{BM}(A)$ computes $\alpha$.

This application is essentially the same as the analogous half of Solovay's argument that "computable from any sufficiently-fast-growing function" is equivalent to hyperarithmeticity, which uses Hechler forcing. So comparing the two forcings involved is  a natural next step.